# Solr facet query filtering

Tags: solr

I'm trying to build a facet query on the manufacturer field when the search term = "LENS" but want to eliminate all those manufactures where there is no lens..

For example:- I need the following output but want to eliminate "Kodak" since there is not lens from that manufacturer....

```
"facet_fields": {
  "manu" : [
    "Canon USA": 25,
    "Olympus": 21,
    "Sony": 12,
    "Panasonic": 9,
    "Nikon": 4,
    "Kodak":0
  ],

http://localhost/solr/collection1/select?q=lens&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.query=lens&facet.field=manu
```

does not yield the correct result

Comment: What result do you get and what do you expect? Kodak is not present in the example you've given..

Comment: @Mats: I have edited the result...Kodak is actually set to zero..I want to know if I can filter the results from the facet query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`facet.mincount`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.mincount) to only retrieve facet keys that have a value above a certain treshold. This is 0 by default.

```
facet.mincount=1
```

You can also supply the value on a per-field basis if you're doing multiple facets in a single request, `f.manu.facet.mincount=1`.

Additionally, there should be no need to do a facet.query when you're already performing the same query as the actual query. The facet.query is useful if you want to do arbitrary queries for a facet, within the same document set already returned by your query.